# Как вычислить количество комбинированных элементов?

Tags: python, комбинаторика

#### Добры день!

У меня есть строка кода где я пишу:

```
combined_elements = combinations(glob_elem, m)
```

Моя задача вычислить количество скомбинированных элементов...

Я решил эту проблему вот так так:

```
comb_length = len(list(combined_elements))
```

Но тут такая проблема что, если элементов внутри массива который я подаю в функцию **`combinations()`** превышает 84, он мне выдаст **`MemoryError`** и программа прекратит работу...

Но если я закомментирую или уберу строку `comb_length = len(list(combined_elements))` и подам массив длиной 1000 в функцию `combinations()`, он его выполнит без ошибок..

Потом попробовал второй способ:

```
def get_length(my_combined_list):
    length = 0
    try:
        while my_combined_list.next():
            length += 1
    except StopIteration:
        #ignored
    return length
```

Второй работает, но к сожалению долго...

Каким еще способом можно вычислить количество сгенерированных сочетаний элементов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваша задача заключается только в вычислении количества элементов, то ее можно свести к вычислению числа сочетаний:

```
In [1]: from math import factorial

In [2]: def c(n, k):
   ...:     return factorial(n) // factorial(k) // factorial(n - k)
   ...: 

In [3]: c(84, 10)
Out[3]: 2761025887620
```

---

> Но если я закомментирую или уберу строку comb_length =
>   len(list(combined_elements)) и подам массив длиной 1000 в функцию
>   combinations(), он его выполнит без ошибок..

Это из-за того, что функция `combinations` является ленивой - она возвращает итератор, реальные данные будут вычисляться только при итерировании по нему (с использованием `list`, к примеру).

Comment: Хмм)) Сработало)) А ведь все так просто :D